# I'm having trouble executing the batch file

Tags: java, batch-file, windows-services, tomcat9

I've been having a hard time for a few days, so I'm visiting Stack Overflow.

I'm currently using Tomcat 9 on a Java web server(openJDK11). Implemented to run batch-file of server using Runtime.

However, it works with eclipse debugging, but it doesn't work when you register with Windows service.

What's the cause? And what is the solution?
Let me know the answer.

**Summary:**

```
WebServer(Eclipse) -> batch-file1 -> batch-file2 : success

WebServer(windows service) -> batch-file1 -> batch-file2 : Fail
```

**Java Code :**

```
String command = "C:\\TOMCAT9\\bin\\getAuth_restart.bat";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

**My Batch-file 1 :**
@echo off

```
echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
set params = %*:"=""
echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k ""%~dp0\restart.bat"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

"%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
```

**My Batch-File 2 (restart.bat) :**

```
taskkill /F /FI "services eq MyService" timeout /t 5 >nul
net start MyService
```

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Check if your service is running as system or a specific user. Use ProcessBuilder instead of Runtime to capture stdout/err and the exit code to get more error information.

Comment: Recent versions of Tomcat by default run as `LocalService`. Older ones ran as `SYSTEM`.

Comment: wow... The problem was that the service was a LocalService!
I changed the service to LocalSystem by performing the following command, and it works fine.

sc config Myservice obj=LocalSystem

Comment: please add that as an answer (and accept it) to remove this question from the "unanswered" queue.